# Light Box prevent close of lightbox on click outside of the box or press esc button

Tags: jquery, lightbox

hiiii,
       i have a jquery lightbox (from [Light Box](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)).. It is working well. But i want some changes:

1. It should not close on click outside of box;
2. it should not close on press Esc Key.

   I am beginner in Jquery, so please help

Comment: It doesn't offer such options, which means you'll have to edit the source. The part of code responsible closing your lightbox is `self.end();` and `this.end();` https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/src/js/lightbox.js Look at the `if` on line 415 for the esc key. And lines 95 -110 for the click events. This isn't a thorough explanation, so I'm no posting it as the answer because I'll be downvoted. But that's basically what you need to do.

Comment: if it is feasible for you to move to any other plugin i would suggest using bootstraps modal.js file and the corresponding css which provides you with options to disable these events from being fired

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Check and remove `$('#lightbox').hide()` or `$('#lightbox').fadeIn()`
on outer div click events.

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mayoung/6TNrw/